# how to connect multiple gsm modem and get response of all modem

Tags: c#, vb.net, serial-port

hi i have following code to connect gsm modem using com port this code works fine on single modem i have more than 10 modems.i want to connect all modems and get response of every modem SerialDataReceiveEvent Serprately question is i need to paste this code 10 times or any other easy way to connect all modems at same time and get every modem response seprately.

```
Public WithEvents DataPort As New IO.Ports.SerialPort
 Public Function ConnectPort(ByVal PrtName As String)
    Try

        DataPort.PortName = PrtName
        DataPort.BaudRate = 115200
        DataPort.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
        DataPort.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
        DataPort.DataBits = 8
        DataPort.Open()
        AddHandler Me.DataPort.DataReceived, New  SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(AddressOf comPort_DataReceived)

        Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

   Public Sub comPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim RecievedMessage As String = DataPort.ReadExisting()
    ModemResponse(RecievedMessage)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can connect multiple modem, for that you can make your application multithreaded. In this case each thread will represent to one modem object but will share the same code also.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste the code 10 times (changing the port number/name each time), but a better approach would be to use a for loop to create the 10 ports. You then need your event handler to know which port the data has arrived from (because your single handler will be called by allthe ports) - you can use `sender` or possibly may be able to get the port number from the event args.

Note that there is no need to deliberately make your code 'multi threaded' because the serial port will do this for you - the event handler will be called back on different thread(s) as data arrives. As long as your event handler doesn't do anything non-thread-safe (such as storing data from different ports in the same place) you won't need to do anything specific to make it multithreaded.